# Singly list insert function in c

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write some functions for simply linked lists. This one is supposed to add a node somewhere in between the list. The user puts in the head of the list, the data "c" which is supposed to be saved at this point, and an int "x" which is the index where it shall be saved. But it basically does nothing and I am not sure why. Maybe someone can see a mistake.

The first if statement is just to check if the index is part of the list.

```
DoubleNode *insert(DoubleNode *head, double c, int x)
{
    int i;
    DoubleNode *cursor, *tmp, *newl;
    cursor = head->next;
    newl = head;
    if (x > Index(newl) || x < 1)
    {
        printf("FAIL\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            newl->next = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            if (i == x)
            {
                tmp = malloc(sizeof(DoubleNode));
                if (tmp == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Fail");
                    return NULL;
                }
                tmp->data = c;
                tmp->next = cursor;
                cursor = tmp;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return newl;
}
```

Comment: I get stuck at the `while (cursor != NULL)`. What value will `cursor` have for an empty list?

Comment: What does `Index(newl)` do?

Comment: The function Index(newl) is part of a bigger programm it just counts how many nodes are in the list. So the index cant be bigger then the elements in the list.

Comment: @BoPersson if the list is empty cursor will be NULL need to check that case right, but that doesnt matter so much right now because its not working in a filled list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to find the predecessor of the node with index x. Allocate a new node and insert it at next node to the found predecessor node.

```
DoubleNode* insert(DoubleNode*head, double c, int x)
{
    if ( x<1 )
    {
        printf("FAIL\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Find predecessor, start with head
    DoubleNode *pred= head;
    int i = 1;
    while ( i < x && pred->next != NULL )
    {
        pred = pred->next;
        i ++;
    }

    if ( i < x )
    {
        // list is to short
        printf("Fail");
        return NULL;
    }

    // allocate new node and insert it after predecessor
    DoubleNode *newl = malloc(sizeof(DoubleNode));
    newl->data = c;
    newl->next = pred->next; // successor of new node is successor of predecessor
    pred->next = newl; // successor of predecessor is now the new node

    return newl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statements

```
tmp->data=c;
tmp->next=cursor;
cursor=tmp;
```

doesn't actually add the node `tmp` to the list. You need to do e.g.

```
tmp->data = c;
tmp->next = cursor->next
cursor->next = tmp;
break;  // No need to loop more, we've inserted the node
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips guys. It is working now. I wanted to return a new head of a full list with the new node in it. I did not mentioned this sorry.

```
DoubleNode*insert(DoubleNode*head, double c, int x)
{
    DoubleNode *pred, *tmp;
        pred=head;
        tmp=head;
        int i = 1;
        while ( i < x && pred->next != NULL )
        {
            pred = pred->next;
            tmp->next=pred;
            i ++;
        }

        if ( i < x )
        {
            printf("Fail");
            return NULL;
        }
        DoubleNode *newl = malloc(sizeof(DoubleNode));
        newl->data = c;
        newl->next = pred->next; 
        pred->next = newl; 

        return tmp;
}
```

Comment: no need to see this i guess. a simple thank you is accepting the correct answer (and other answers that is helpful for you)

Comment: Well sorry kinda new here. thought if someone with the same problems come over here wants to see how i ended up and dont have to ask for the same.